# I want to get the phone number from the about phone setting in react native

Tags: android, react-native

I want my app to automatically get the phone number and add it in the textview. For getting the phone number I have used const phoneNumber = DeviceInfo.getPhoneNumber(); method of the 'react-native-device-info' library. The issue I am facing is that when the app asks for the permission from the user and the user allow the permission than the permission will be granted to the app but I am not able to get the phone number but when I restart the app then I will be able to get the phone number.

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Picker, StyleSheet, View, Text, TouchableOpacity, Image, StatusBar, PermissionsAndroid} from 'react-native';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
import DeviceInfo from 'react-native-device-info';

export default class Login_first extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.onComplete = this.onComplete.bind(this);
        this._retrieveData = this._retrieveData.bind(this);
        this.state = {            
            number:"",
            dummy:""
        }
        this._retrieveData();    
    }

    async requestPermission() {
        try {
          const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_PHONE_STATE)

          if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
            console.log("You can read the phone state");            
          } else {
            console.log("permission denied")
          }
        } catch (err) {
          console.warn(err)
        }
      }

    _retrieveData = async () => {
        try {
          const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('visited_onces');
          if (value !== null ) {            
            this.props.navigation.replace('Welcome_back',{Json_value:value});
            console.log(value);
          }
        } catch (error) {          
          alert(error);
        }        
      };

    onComplete(){     
      const phoneNumber = DeviceInfo.getPhoneNumber();   
      alert(phoneNumber);
      //this.props.navigation.replace('Login_second',{mobile:phoneNumber});
    }
    componentDidMount() {
      this.requestPermission()
    }
    render() {       
        const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;        
        return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <StatusBar
                barStyle="light-content"
            />
            <View style={{justifyContent:'center',alignItems:'center'}}>
                <TouchableOpacity style={{backgroundColor:'#d4e09b',width:'100%'}} onPress={()=>{this.onComplete()}}>
                    <Text style={styles.next_btn}>Next</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        </View>        
        );
    }
}

});
```

The output I am getting after allowing the permission to the app is null which means the app has no permission to access the phone number but when I close the app and restart the app I can get the phone number which will be inside About phone -> Status ->sim status.

Comment: I think it would be better to make two screens and use one screen exclusively for permission and one by importing device information.

Comment: I have tried it by doing it like when the button is clicked it will navigate to the second page and on the second page in componentDidMount() method have I have written const phoneNumber = DeviceInfo.getPhoneNumber(); alert(phoneNumber); but still getting null in the alert for the first time and once I close app and reopen it than I am able to get mobile number

Comment: Are you testing with a physical device?

Comment: Yes. I am testing in Moto E(4) plus by USB debugging and in onePlus 7 by creating apk file.

Comment: could you try get `READ_SMS` `READ_CONTACTS` ?

Comment: ref link https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getLine1Number()

Comment: I have no idea about how to use TelephonyManager but I tried using both the above permission but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to call the _retrieveData on the permission granted.

e.g-

```
if (granted == PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
        console.log("You can read the phone state");   
       this._retrieveData();    
      }
```

Comment: Thanks for reply @Gopal Awasthi. But here I am not facing issue in getting data from async storage but I am facing issue in oncomplete() method where I am trying to get the mobile number.

Comment: @Maq That means you are not getting the number from the code const phoneNumber = DeviceInfo.getPhoneNumber();

Comment: Yes, correct. Is there any other way around for getting the mobile number?

Comment: You cannot be able to get the number on the iOS. For android i think you should use the library https://github.com/pocesar/react-native-sim-data

Comment: I tried the react-native-sim-data library, I am facing exactly the same issue for this library too. I can read the phone number second time after giving permission I need to restart app than only I can ready the phone number.

Comment: you have to make the _retrievdata function awaitable so call await this._retrievdata(). This is a threading issue if the view did not reder the phone number only for the first time. Just make sure when you allow the permission just after that the function will call  Hope this help!!

Comment: I have created one project with this much of code but didn't work.

async requestPermission() {
try {
const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_PHONE_STATE)
if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
console.log("You can read the phone state");
}
} catch (err) { console.warn(err) }}
btn_click(){
alert(RNSimData.getSimInfo().phoneNumber0);
}
componentDidMount() {
 this.requestPermission()
}
render() {
return (
<View>
<Text>hello</Text>
<Button title="Click me" onPress={()=>{this.btn_click()}}/>
      </View>
    );
  }

Comment: @Maq did you find any solution?

Comment: @Maq, did you managed to get it to work? If yes, do you mind to share the solution? :)